# Eclipse c++ project folders

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a lot of classes in my project which means a lot of files too. I want to put everything in subfolders so it's a grouped together and a bit more clear.

There is already a folder names scr where all my cpp and header files are in but I want to create a folder named 'products' and put all the product-related files in there.

But when I do so, I get this error (after pressing build) that one of my classes can't be build. It says:

> make: *** [scr/Producten/AudioKaart.o] Error 1    KassaSysteem            C/C++
>   Problem recipe for target `scr/Producten/AudioKaart.o'
>   failed    subdir.mk   /KassaSysteem/Debug/scr/Producten   line 30 C/C++
>   Problem

**What's the right way to put files in subfolders?** Do I need to change the includes? Or do something more than just dragging and dropping them into the folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you put headers in your Producten directory, you need to include this directory in your project settings. Another way is to include your header by specifying the sub-directory, something like

```
#include "Producten/xxx.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses directories for project folders, so you need to adjust all includes as well.